# Mirror partner of Calabi-Yau threefold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

There are Calabi-Yau threefolds that do not have  Calabi-Yau threefolds as their mirror partners like rigid ones ($h^{1,2} =0$).

I am wondering if there are known any examples of non-rigid Calabi-Yau threefolds that do not have Calabi-Yau threefolds as their mirrors.